# Weekly writing exercise: keeping logs

Tags: discussion, writing-exercise

After 25th March 2014 writing exercise, a question came up about how do we keep a log of the exercises and its contents (refer [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14479753#14479753)). In response to the same, I propose that we keep a log of the chat conversation [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14480940#14480940) way:

> I was thinking about how we can keep a log of all the writing exercises. Each week after the session is over, the person who initiated the chat can post on Meta:  Week : Writing Exercise
>
> with details about the topic and the number of people participated. All the people who wrote/shared links can then put their writing as an answer. In case the person is not a member of Writers, someone else could post it on his/her behalf.

Advantages:

- Easily accessible record of all the topics and the writings (along with the links)
- Users who missed the chat can quickly find out the details of the exercise
- People who read this later might find it interesting enough to participate in the subsequent week
- People who are not keen on writing but are keen on reading can find content here without having to hunt it up by loading past conversations on chat
- People can paste the actual content (instead of links) for a more permanent record

What do you all think? Opinions? Criticism?

Comment: This is not a bad idea. Worst case scenario you'd have a meta question with only the facilitator's own writing added, and they can delete it if their writing feels lonely. The old system, of using a mishmash of blogs and disparate writing tools, is pretty disorganized. My only concern is whether this kind of thing is appropriate for Meta.

Comment: We can also bookmark the chat logs, [like this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/conversation/weekly-writing-chat-2014-03-25).

Comment: @MonicaCellio This is pretty cool!

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 That's precisely my concern too

Comment: @MonicaCellio Shall I put up this week's "proceedings"?

Comment: @PraveshParekh go for it!  And more generally, especially on a beta site, be bold -- no need to wait for permission for something like this, especially on a beta site where we're all still exploring what works best for the community.  At the very least, collecting the prompt, links to the things that got written, and a link to a chat log sounds like a good idea; expand as you like.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Done (actually did it yesterday but forgot to comment). Have a look maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pravesh has created [an example](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/827/1993) (thanks!) from this week's writing chat.  I suggest that we follow that approach each week (if it needs to be tweaked then tweak it; this isn't cast in stone).  The key points are:

- Create a bookmark from the chat transcript.  Include "Writing Chat" and the date in the bookmark name so it'll be easier to browse bookmarks.  (All bookmarks are linked from the chat room.)
- Create a new meta question following the pattern of the example.  At minimum include the date, who facilitated, who participated, and link to the chat transcript.  Ideally also include answers to collect the writings.  (I'm making that optional because technically they're in the transcript, but we want to make them more accessible than that.)
- Tag posts related to the weekly chat with [writing-exercise](/questions/tagged/writing-exercise).